# convert datastring into the jpgimage

Tags: php, image, jpeg

I am using **sqlserver** as backend server in that we have "image" datatype

image store as following manner

2nd comment of hex Oxffd is the jpg extension

***Above code is in **IMAGE** DATA TYPE itsnot varbinary or binary.***

and we are trying to fecth this data via php and wants to display as image 
but got following code  as result of the select query "select mainpic from 
mytable where id=1"

$url =http://rku.ac.in/library/webopac/photo.php

We are trying to generate image in php

```
<?php 
    $data=file_get_contents($url);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
?>
```

Comment: ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿáÆExifMM* æð1ü2  !"#$%‡i .œ›œŸêÚêmotorolaMoto C PlusMediaTek Camera Application 2018:01:29 09:45:18‚šl‚tˆ"ˆ'n0220|‘’¤’’ÿ’ ’ ¬’28r’‘28’’28 0100  ° @¤k7¤¤´¤j/ê `ê†“B@ 2018:01:29 09:45:182018:01:29 09:45:18 ^dddÿáûhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ 2018-01-29T09:45:18.280MediaTek Camera Application ÿÛC    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!! .... data as response we are getting

Comment: output we are getting in php as data

Comment: 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFE112C64578696600004D4D002A000000080011010E00020000000100000000010F000200000009000008E6011000020000000C000008F0011200030000000100010000013100020000001D000008FC01320002000000140000091A02130003000000010002000602200004000000010000000002210004000000010000000002 ..... database data in sqlserver

Comment: put the whole string

Comment: Could you please EDIT your post/question and paste that code there and not in the comments? Thanks

Comment: `$data=""; $data = base64_decode($data);` What do you expect `$data` to look like after you `base64_decode()`d an empty string?

Comment: Your output looks like it is correct JPEG data already; if the browser _shows_ you this as characters however, that is a pretty sure sign that your ContentType header did not work as expected.